# How to construct image url from Axomic OpenAsset REST API

Tags: rest

I'd like to get the URL for an image that is stored in our [OpenAsset](http://www.axomic.com/) server. I can curl a request to get the file's information:

`curl -u myUsername:myPassword -X GET http://our.IP.address//REST/1/Files/11 | json_pp`

and I can reverse engineer the url that their front end uses to show me an image:

`our.IP.address/Serve/DirectImage/imageId.7235-defaultImageSizeId.1`

But trying to do some kind of string format to make the url feels hacky. E.g.:

`"our.IP.address/Serve/DirectImage/imageId.{}-defaultImageSizeId.1".format(theImageID)`

Is there a way get a url directly from the rest request? Is this the correct way to do it?

The [OpenAsset REST API](http://help.axomic.com/07_Technical_Stuff/APIs_and_Integration/REST_API) is in beta still, so its documentation is surprisingly good given that fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

starting with : `curl -u username:password -X GET  http://my.IP.add.ress//REST/1/Files/`

```
{
    "copyright_holder_id" : "0",
    "download_count" : "1",
    "original_filename" : "C990705_Colleges_011.tif",
    "photographer_id" : "0",
    "contains_video" : "0",
    "md5_now" : "",
    "category_id" : "1",
    "caption" : "",
    "md5_at_upload" : "90d661ec1...06b71",
    "id" : "11",
    "project_id" : "854",
    "click_count" : "2",
    "rotation_since_upload" : "0",
    "alternate_store_id" : "0",
    "duration" : "0",
    "description" : "",
    "created" : "0",
    "filename" : "C990705_N1.tif",
    "uploaded" : "20101202062201",
    "contains_audio" : "0",
    "user_id" : "12",
    "access_level" : "2",
    "rank" : "5"
}
```

Which is the information about the *original* file as it was uploaded. To get to a downloadable file you need to go to the `sizes` route.

`curl -u username:password -X GET  http://my.IP.add.ress//REST/1/Files/11/Sizes | json_pp`

Which gives a list of the possible sizes and formats.

```
[
    {
        "unc_root" : "//SYD-OA001/openasset/",
        "width" : "1383",
        "watermarked" : "0",
        "relative_path" : "Projects/C990705/C990705_N1_tif/C990705_N1_medium.jpg",
        "colourspace" : "RGB",
        "y_resolution" : "150",
        "height" : "666",
        "http_root" : "/Images/",
        "filesize" : "106363",
        "x_resolution" : "150",
        "recreate" : "0",
        "id" : "8",
        "quality" : "0",
        "file_format" : "jpg"
    },
    {
        "width" : "1383",
        "unc_root" : "//SYD-OA001/openasset/",
        "watermarked" : null,
        "relative_path" : "Projects/C990705/C990705_N1.tif",
        "colourspace" : "CMYK",
        "y_resolution" : "300",
        "height" : "666",
        "x_resolution" : "300",
        "filesize" : "3697734",
        "http_root" : "/Images/",
        "id" : "1",
        "quality" : "0",
        "file_format" : "tif"
    }
]
```

To get to the file you want you'll need to search this list for the right size and format, and then concatinate the `unc_root` and the `relative_path`.