# How do I get images from a particular project using the OpenAsset REST API?

Tags: rest

I asked a while ago about [how to get the actual image file from the `File` noun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676924/how-to-construct-image-url-from-axomic-openasset-rest-api) using the [OA REST API](http://help.axomic.com/07_Technical_Stuff/APIs_and_Integration/REST_API).

I'm [confused as to how to retrieve images related to a specific project](http://notionparallax.co.uk/?p=1623).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a [helpful nudge](http://notionparallax.co.uk/?p=1623#comment-4644) from [Jason](http://www.axomic.com/) I've discovered that the secret password is *filtering* using the `params`.

This still feels a bit unpleasant as it requires 4 trips to the OA server, so I'm probably still missing something that would allow me to concatenate these requests into one.

I wrote a short Ruby programme that will go and get a single image to illustrate the principle:

```
baseURL  = "http://IP.A.DDR.ESS"

password = "password"
username = "login"


require 'net/http'
require "uri"
require 'json'

def ask_oa(request, baseURL, params, username, password, useParams)
    #This constructs a REST request, makes it, and returns the JSON response.
    uri = URI.parse(baseURL + request)

    if useParams
        uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    end
    puts uri

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.basic_auth(username, password)
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
    http.request(request)
    }
    json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
    puts JSON.pretty_generate(json_response)

    return json_response
end

puts "Step 1"
#You'll need to change this for *your* project name
project_name = "M020707"
puts "go and get a project where the project number is "+project_name+":"
request  = "/REST/1/Projects"
params = { :textMatching  => "exact",
           :code          => project_name
         }
projectJSON = ask_oa(request, baseURL, params, username, password, true)
projectNumber = projectJSON[0]["id"]
#This ID is the ID of the Project. You use this as the Project_id to
#key into the Files list that we access next

puts "Step 2"
puts "go and get the files that have a project_id of "+projectNumber+":"
request  = "/REST/1/Files"
params = { :textMatching  => "exact",
           :project_id    => projectNumber
         }
fileJSON = ask_oa(request, baseURL, params, username, password, true)
#You'd want a more exciting way of picking a file out of that list
#probably based on the ranking of the files or some other secret knowledge
the_file_I_want = 0
fileID = fileJSON[the_file_I_want]["id"]
#This is a single file, picked from a list of all the files associated
#with the project that we pulled in step 1. Now that we have a file id
#we're back to where we were when I asked my last question on SO.
#To OA, File means the source file, we now need to pick a
#processed/formatted version of it:

puts "Step 3"
puts "go and get the size options for the file with the ID "+fileID+":"
request  = "/REST/1/Files/"+fileID+"/Sizes"
params = {}
sizeJSON = ask_oa(request, baseURL, params, username, password, false)
#implement a picker in here to get the format that you want. 0 is just
#the first, and I don't know if the order that they are provided in is
#deterministic
s = sizeJSON[0]
#This gets to the list of actual files that you can now construct a URL from

puts "Step 4"
puts "Request an image with this URL:"
puts baseURL + s["http_root"] + s["relative_path"]
#Now we can just request the file at the end of
#this url and we'll see a picture!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request image files relating to a project using this endpoint:

`https://your.base.url.com/REST/1/Files?project_id=<PROJ_ID>`

You may also want to apply more complex filtering of projects based on Keywords, this is many times how users will differentiate projects through "keyword tagging":

Using the `filterBy` parameter you can select Files that contain specific keywords like so: `filterBy[keyword_id][]=<KEYWORD_ID>`

You will need to grab your keyword ID by querying `/Keywords` and finding the ID of the one you want. I'm not suggesting hardcoding this.

Back to Image File queries, you can also pull in various remote fields from other object types using this syntax:
`remoteFields[]=<FIELD_NAME>`

So for example, to get the photographer name you could put another parameter on your File query:
`&remoteFields[]=photographer`

This is what our complete query example looks like:

`{{baseURL}}/REST/1/Files?project_id=555&filterBy[keyword_id][]=777&remoteFields[]=photographer`